# Formatting Columns with cout and Strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, formatting, cout

Good evening! I was hoping I might ask your assistance with formatting strings in a cout statement.

The goal is to have all columns align left with a max width of `colWidth`.

In the output below, you'll notice the column widths perform as desired unless the string length is below the column width (as with inventory item 3). If I replace the `string(strArray[i].begin(), strArray[i].begin() + colWidth)` with `strArray[i]`, the exact opposite occurs where any string elements that are below the column max are fine, but anything else overflows and pushes out the text.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string strArray[20] = {"mumblemumble1","mumblemumblemumble2","mumble3","mumblemumblemumblemumble4","mumblemumblemumble5","mumble6","mumblemumblemumblemumble7","mumblemumblemumble8","mumble9","mumblemumblemumblemumble10","mumblemumble11","mumblemumblemumble12","mumble13","mumblemumblemumblemumble14","mumblemumblemumble15","mumblemumble16","mumblemumblemumble17","mumble18","mumblemumblemumblemumble19","mumblemumblemumble20"};
    int cols = 2;       // The number of columns to display
    int colWidth = 10;  // Width allowed for title output
    int colCount = 0;   // Used with mod (%) to provide a new line when needed

    cout << endl << endl << "Number of titles in inventory: " << 20;
    cout << endl << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(4) << right << (i + 1) << ") " << left << setw(colWidth) << string(strArray[i].begin(),strArray[i].begin() + colWidth);
        if ((i+1) % cols == 0)
            cout << endl;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
Number of titles in inventory: 20

   1) mumblemumb   2) mumblemumb
   3) mumble3   4) mumblemumb
   5) mumblemumb   6) mumble6
   7) mumblemumb   8) mumblemumb
   9) mumble9  10) mumblemumb
  11) mumblemumb  12) mumblemumb
  13) mumble13  14) mumblemumb
  15) mumblemumb  16) mumblemumb
  17) mumblemumb  18) mumble18
  19) mumblemumb  20) mumblemumb
```

Comment: This code `string(strArray[i].begin(),strArray[i].begin() + colWidth)` throws an exception when the string is shorter than 10 characters ('mumble3' for example).

Comment: Ahh - I wasn't able to see that on my terminal. Thank you!

Comment: Was that the only issue?

Comment: I believe so - it was part of a much larger issue I'm coming to realize is stemming from input file strings capturing \r returns from windows files and messing up the formatting further. Deleting the question above momentarily. Thank you for the assist!

Comment: You can check the size of the string and then if it is too small append blank spaces " " until it is long enough. That should avoid the exception and keep the formatting you want.

Comment: That's unfortunately where the breakdown is occurring: when I append, interestingly, the appended string `cout`s at the beginning of the line, overwriting the beginning of the line. This is what's leading me to believe \r is involved... Saving windows .dat files on a unix compiler isn't helping the situation either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code `string(strArray[i].begin(),strArray[i].begin() + colWidth)` throws an exception when the string is shorter than 10 characters ('mumble3' for example).

Change your for loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    string str = strArray[i];
    while (str.size() < colWidth) {
        str = str + " ";
    }
    cout << setw(4) << right << (i + 1) << ") " << left << setw(colWidth) << string(str.begin(), str.begin() + colWidth);
    if ((i + 1) % cols == 0)
        cout << endl;
}
```